# Why add text changed event is required and how we can add in Aurelia app

Tags: typescript, aurelia

is this way we can add text changed event ? share some useful link where i can learn Aurelia application

## textbox.ts

```
export class Textbox {

  @bindable textValue='';
  @bindable displayName: string;

  constructor(controllerFactory) {
    this.controller = controllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    this.controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.changeOrBlur;
    this.controller.addRenderer(new BootstrapFormRenderer());    
  }

  attached() : void {
    this.controller.validate(); 
  }
}

ValidationRules
.ensure((c:Textbox) => c.textValue)
.required().withMessage("This field is required!")
.maxLength(50)
.on(Textbox);
```

## textbox.html

```
   <input type="text" placeholder.bind="placeholder" onchange="alert('textvalue changed')"  class="form-control" value.bind="textValue & validate">
```

## app.html

```
<template>
<textbox></textbox>
</template>
```

Comment: you are confusing aurelia with angular. in aurelia you write `value.bind="values"` instead of `[(value)]="values"`. you don't need to handle any event - becaue of the two way data binding system.

Comment: I have updated onchange event in textbox.html. is this text change event or this is one(change.delege="")

Comment: you could use delegate, but I highly suggest you follow the contact manager tutorial first to grasp the basics: https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager at the end of the tutorial they show how you can listen to property changes in your VM: https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager#adding-a-loading-indicator